# How do I set up router in Vue SSR?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I use Laravel7, vue@2.6.11, @vue/cli 4.1.1

In this configuration, the following happens:
When I click on the "formula" route, the transition occurs and the page is render.

And if I refresh the page, the page not render content of the component "formula".

How do I make the page render when I log in
to the website on the formula page?

**app.js**

```
import App from './components/App.vue';
import Vue from 'vue';
import router from './router'

export default new Vue({
  router,
  render: h => h(App)
});
```

**App.Vue**

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <router-view></router-view>
     <router-link :to="{ name: 'Formula' }">Formula</router-link>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default{
data() {
   return {
app_id: null,
     }
   },
}
</script>
```

**router.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Router from 'vue-router'
Vue.use(Router);

import Formula from './components/formula/formula'

export default new Router({
  mode: 'history',
  routes: [
      {path: '/formula', component: Formula, name: 'Formula'},
      ]
      });
```

**entry-server.js**

```
import app from './app'
import router from './router';
new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  router.push(url);
  router.onReady(() => {
    const matchedComponents = router.getMatchedComponents();
    if (!matchedComponents.length) {
      return reject({ code: 404 });
    }
    resolve(app);
  }, reject);
})
  .then(app => {
    renderVueComponentToString(app, (err, res) => {
      print(res);
    });
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    print(err);
  });
```

**entry-client.js**

```
import app from './app'
app.$mount('#app');
```

**app.blade.php**(index.html)

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="{{ app()->getLocale() }}">
<body>
    {!! $ssr !!}
    <script src="{{ asset('js/entry-client.js') }}" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Why is this happening?
How do I fix it?

Comment: @LawrenceCherone I add index.html in my post.

Comment: ok, so when you go to `/formula` in browser whats showing?

Comment: @LawrenceCherone if I click on the link, it is rendered, and if I update the page, it does not display anything. In the console, writes: entry-client.js: `The client-side rendered virtual DOM tree is not matching server-rendered content. This is likely caused by incorrect HTML markup, for example nesting block-level elements inside <p>, or missing <tbody>. Boiling hydration and performing full client-side rendering.`